# how to import file without ts declarations

Tags: javascript, typescript

one of my file contains this

```js
export { print }
```

You can neglect the `print` . they are some variables.

I import these in one of the files.

```js
import { print } from '../lib/filename';
```

But this results in an error: `Could not find a declaration file for module '../lib/filename'`

It's true that I don't have declarations for this while, but I want to make this error go away, but somehow I want to achieve this without breaking some ts rules. at least, let's break the least rules.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Why not just add a declaration file (or convert `filename` into a `.ts` file right away)?

Comment: Is the `export { print }` file a `.js` file? Any reason not to make it a `.ts` file?